# JQuery UI dialog('open') doesnt work with selector

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I'm able to create a jquery ui dialog using the following:

```
    $("#dialogs .add_entry").dialog
    ({
         height: 500, 
         width: 750, 
         autoOpen: false, 
         stack: true, 
         show: "fade", 
         resizable: true, 
         title: "Add Entry", 
         modal: true
    });

    <div id="dialogs">
        <div class="add_entry">Test</div>
    </div>
```

But when I later use $("#dialogs .add_entry").dialog("open"); to open the dialog nothing happens (No js errors). I think it is selector related, switching the autoOpen to true shows the dialog. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $element = $("#dialogs .add_entry");
    $element.dialog({
        height:500,
        width:750,
        stack: true, 
        show: "fade", 
        resizable: true, 
        title: "Add Entry", 
        autoOpen:false, 
        modal: true
    });
    $element.dialog("open");
});
```

This works if placed BEFORE the element.  Does not work after.  Also does not work with out variable, does not work without wrapper function... what a buggy function.

Comment: I've tried an onClick, onLoad, placing it directly after initializing the dialog. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I pasted my findings above.  Try binding an event at $element.dialog("open"); you might have to pull some tricks to get around closure.

Comment: Ya np.  Javascript is buggy overall imho.  Simply calling a function to make something function? hahaha, Javascript laughs at your presumption of simplicity.  sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#dialogs > .add_entry")
```

OR

```
$("#dialogs").children(".add_entry")
```